# How to get the ID of search button in Liferay search portlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, liferay-6

I am using `Liferay Search portlet`.In which I want to get the Id of search button of `<liferay-ui:search/>` tag.also I want to trigger a 'auto click' event on 'search button'.

Comment: Using jQuery , you can get search image by $('.portlet-search input[type=image]')..as liferay-ui:search tag uses input image type for search button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery , you can get search image by $('.portlet-search input[type=image]')..as liferay-ui:search tag uses input image type for search button.